# Apache virtual host configuration error

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

I have website `www.example.com.`
I have created virtual host for this in Ubuntu server and it is successfully map it to the `www.example.com.`
     But when i tried to run `http://example.com` without "WWW" then it will not go the specific virtual host. 
Should i have to create virtual host again with `http://example.com`?
Server: Ubuntu Server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the ServerAlias:

```
ServerAlias *.example.com
```